# VREF of FPGA should be grounded if not needed?

Tags: fpga, voltage-reference

I just started FPGAs. I know that Vref is designed for I/O Banks specially needed for some I/O standards or weak keeping. If I dont need them should I ground these pins or leave them floating( not connected)?

EDITION: specifically I mean [XC2S100  in Spartan II](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds001.pdf) group.

Comment: [obvious question]  What model of FPGA have you got?  Post a link to the datasheet, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you only need to connect to the Vrefs on the bank with your single input.

Here is a quote from the [Xilinx web site](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/hmg/le/project-home/xilinx/ise_8.1/doc/usenglish/de/libs/lib/ibuf4816.pdf):

> **Input Banking (VREF) Rules** The low-voltage I/O standards that have a differential amplifier input require a voltage reference input
>   (VREF). The VREF voltage source is provided as an external signal to
>   the chip. • Any input buffer component that does not require a VREF
>   source (LVTTL, LVCMOS2, PCI) can be placed in any bank. • All input
>   buffer components that require a VREF source (GTL*, HSTL*, SSTL*, CTT,
>   AGP) must be of the same I/O standard in a particular bank. For
>   example, IBUF with I/O standard (SSTL2_I) and IBUFG with I/O standard
>   (SSTL2_I) are compatible since they are the same I/O standard.
>
> - If the bank contains any input buffer component that requires a    VREF source, the following conditions apply.
> - One or more VREF    sources must be connected to the bank via an IOB.
> - The number of VREF sources is dependent on the device and package.
> - The locations of the VREF sources are fixed for each device/package.
> - All VREF ources must be used in that bank.
> - • If the bank contains no inputbuffer component that requires a VREF source, the IOBs for VREF sources can be used for general I/O.
>
>   - • Output buffer components of    any type can be placed in the bank.